# Resetting rules for non comutative multiply

Tags: replacement, physics, rule, quantum-computing

Im currently working on a project that intends to achieve multiple task the first if which rewrite a bra-ket notated triplet tensor product state such as the w state in terms of the pauli matrices.
i,e:

```
w = (1/sqrt[3])*{bra[{0, 0, 1}], bra[{0, 1, 0}], bra[{1, 0, 0}]};
wbar = ReplaceAll[w, {0 -> 1, 1 -> 0}];
wket = ReplaceAll[w, {bra -> ket}];
wbarket = ReplaceAll[wk, {bra -> ket}];
density matrix = Tuples[{wket, w}]
and I apply 
rules = {{0, 0} -> {e/2, Z/2}, {0, 1} -> {X/2, IY/2}, {1, 
     0} -> {X/2, -IY/2}, {1, 1} -> {e/2, -Z/2}};
```

with a new rule for non comutative multiply
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
NonCommutativeMultiply

```
[x___, n_ y_, z___] /; NumberQ[n] := 
 n x ** y ** 
Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
```

but for the next section, I simply want to check if a matrix made of the w and w bar states is unitary and the rule I applied above gets in the way. is there a way to remove that rule after that section or make it only apply to one section of the code?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Are you aware of the [NCAlgebra](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/) package?

Comment: Hello, Cant say I am. Do you belive it is suited for this project and do you know any means of removing previously added rules? as that's currently whats ruining my project since both rules are applying att once :)